# On "That Hyphenated Site"

Tags: discussion, fun, experts-exchange

OK, which one of you jokers (oh, and I *know* it was one of you) did this?

http://expert-sex-change.com

:)

Don't bother looking up the WHOIS, it's anonymized through GoDaddy.

Also, for the record, I have nothing against "That Hyphenated Site". I for one applaud what they do, because [they make our life so, *so* very easy](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001246.html). Don't ever change, you magnificent bastards!

Comment: Sweet.  Well worth 10 bucks a year.

Comment: Related: [What Experts-Exchange thinks of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92683/131713), [Funny observation about Experts-Exchange and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35453/131713)

Answer (score 15):

If you asked a question about a sex change on SO, would somebody try answering it before it got closed for the rep? I'm willing to put $10 on "Yes."

Comment: Would I receive said $10 directly for attempting?

Comment: If you can get somebody to answer it, yes.

Comment: The sex change or the question?

Comment: Someone asked it. And yes, it did get answers prior to being closed and deleted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788294

Comment: Quick. Upvote my stuff so I can hit 10k and view this evidence!

Comment: show us a pic of the question, please!

Answer (score 5):

It's not subtle enough.

Comment: +1 - I agree.  Should probably be something like http://expertsexchange.com as people would be more likely to enter it like *that* when they actually want to go to 'the hypen site'

Comment: The site with a hypen owns the non-hypened version of the name as well.

Comment: Correction: The site with a hypen *was* the non-hypened version of the name *originally*.

Answer (score 3):

Now this looks better with LMGTFY

[http://expert-sex-change.com/On “That Hyphenated Site”](http://expert-sex-change.com/On%20%E2%80%9CThat%20Hyphenated%20Site%E2%80%9D)

Comment: Damn, you got me stuck in a loop now!