# Does it make sense to be on Experts-Exchange when we have Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business

Is there any reason to pay the fee for [Experts-Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange) and ask questions there too?

Comment: You can usually get good enough answers on expert-sex-change by scrolling to the bottom of the page, without paying!

Comment: Don't name the site that shall not be named.

Comment: Wait - people PAY for that site?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no good reason to be on expert-sexchange.

Comment: I don't like the site either, but it has its audience and they probably have no good reason to be on stackoverflow.

Comment: Even though EE lost some of it's value since they started charging members for the answers, I still consider EE a valuable resource. Then again, I've earned enough points there to avoid having to pay for answers. Never paid them a dime, just provided them with lots of answers.

Comment: (-1) If my answer is there, that's a pretty good reason for me to be there. Also, you got the name of the website wrong.

Comment: @devinb - Time-delayed *whoosh*

Answer (score 17):

I actually never liked Experts-Exchange anyway.

StackOverflow is free, looks better, has better functionality and is simple.

I think that StackOverflow will ground the future of online support / help communities in general. It brings fluent a fluent feeling of usage without stubbornity. (yeah, that word doesn't exist, but anyway ;p)

Also, with the time StackOverflow will have way more hits on google or other search engines than Experts-Exchange ;-)

Comment: @devinb: do you feel personally agravated for those of us that make fun of the poor choise of name expertsexchange.com once made?

Answer (score 6):

I won't ask new questions in Experts-Exchange, but I sometimes get answers for some questions there, mostly through Google Search.

Comment: Since more actively using SO, I regularly pay attention to the quality of answers from EE in search results. There are some good questions but the quality of answers is so poor that I never click through any more. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

People at Experts Exchange should read Joel's article [The Day My Industry Died](http://joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/07/23c.html). This is exactly what SO did to EE :)

Comment: Fog Creek survived, though, didn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Next time you visit EE, remember that they've updated their URL to the new [Expert-Sex-Change.com](http://expert-sex-change.com/). Update your bookmarks and favourite stars accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure that Jeff and Joel really want their brand associated with a website called "Expert-Sex-Change"?

Comment: Linking SO to sex, bad move! (-1)

Comment: Can't quite find the discussion on Meta that this URL was first brought up.

Comment: Should have been http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/on-that-hyphenated-site

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No
Reason: Click on EE link from google, when page loads, click on the "END" key on keyboard.
BOOM! Correct answer provided. No charge.