# Funny observation about Experts-Exchange and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, experts-exchange

I was searching Google for a question about JavaScript string byte length and opened some of the results in a bunch of tabs without looking at the URLs. One of the pages was an Experts-Exchange question that was exactly what I was looking for.

(In my defense, I had searched Stack Overflow earlier and hadn't found a good enough answer, and was getting ready to ask the question myself, but thought I'd do some more Google digging first).

I scrolled down to the bottom of the page to actually see the answers, and what do I find?

The best answer on Experts Exchange... was a link to a question on Stack Overflow!

Haha. I literally lolled for a few seconds and then came here to share this wonderful find.

See it [on EE directly](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_20741247.html) or [via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aexperts-exchange.com+How+can+I+find+byte+value+of+a+string+with+javascript).

Scroll down to the very last answer posted by andrejonker. Classic!

Comment: You have to google the title and then click on the google link. E-Sex-C hides the answers when the refer(r)er isn't google.

Comment: Didn't look like an answer. More a comment.

Comment: However the SO link is only a discussion opened, not the accepted answer, from what I see.

Comment: So do the EE accounts that get caught posting S[OFU] links get banned for treason?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If EE can get people to pay for links to SO, then kudos to them. As they say, there's one born every minute.

The silver lining is that EE visitors will discover a better resource. Sadly, however, we cannot help them change back to their original gender.

Comment: So how about converts who haven't logged into our EE accounts since the inception of SOFU? :)

Comment: @squillman - are you saying you used to be squillwoman?

Comment: Long enough to get a few K points at EE, now back to normal.

Comment: the little kicker sentence you added at the end totally snuck up on me, LOL

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: For anyone not familiar, ExpertsExchange can be read as ExpertSexChange.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if the question is asking how to find the *byte value* of a string, or *how many* bytes it contains.  Either way, the *accepted* answer:

> No can do in JavaScript, it's a highlevel language it's not C.

is the real "WTF?" here.

Comment: Perhaps Experts-Exchange == Yahoo Answers for techs?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a few of those.

Experts-Exchange may be winning the battle of top results, but we're winning the war:

[image: ARE YOU READY FOR A WAR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]
<sub>(source: [buddycremeans.com](http://www.buddycremeans.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/braveheart.jpg))</sub>

Comment: We can't lose: we have donuts on our side.

Comment: I always assume EE is paid, so I can't look at it, so there's no game for me.

Comment: @Daniel: EE is _never_ paid for that.  If it's in google search results, you _can_ see it.  What you have to pay for now is the ability to ask new questions and removing a bunch of the ads.

Comment: You answer enough questions to become an "expert" and it's free.  But their format blows....

Comment: @Gaspar: and waffles and ponies, and especially... lasers!

Comment: Is that Peter Petrelli on the right (left on the image) of Mad Max?

Comment: @Joel Somehow, I never see the responses. A trial is offered every time I try to visualize one. Maybe they are hidden somewhere in the middle of all the ads, but if this is so, I can't find them. --> Oops! I just found the answers now! After scrolling down a lot, they are there! I don't remember having seen them before. My mistake.