# expert-sex-change.com?

Tags: discussion, experts-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On “That Hyphenated Site”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/on-that-hyphenated-site)

Sorry if I missed something, but did everyone else know about [expert-sex-change.com](http://expert-sex-change.com)?

I was messing around on the Area 51 web applications proposal domain names, and tried typing this in to the http://instantdomainsearch.com/ ... found it had been registered ..... and it landed me at a well-known website ...........

Comment: That is troubling to me.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15297/on-that-hyphenated-site

Comment: I think the domain owner outed themselves somewhere on meta... but I'm not sure

Comment: OK, so everyone did know about this. Somehow the search didn't show it up.

Comment: I have an account there??? I swear I have never visited nor registered on expert-sex-change.com :-)

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, a few of those knocking about. A while back the energy company Powergen registered their Italian site 'Powergen Italia'. www.powergenitalia.com . It's no longer up but the wayback machine stil has it

http://web.archive.org/web/20020121051236/http://www.powergenitalia.com/

Also www.therapistfinder.com (for find therapists) and www.whorepresents.com (for finding celebrity agents.)

Not really sure this belongs on meta!

Comment: Oh, yes it does. Did you try the site?